# PDF with embedded font subset displays as gibberish on iPhone

Tags: c#, pdf

I have made C# software to write PDFs ( [on github here](https://github.com/georgebarwood/pdf) ), however PDFs with an embedded font subset which display fine in Adobe reader and other readers come out garbled on an iPhone. An example test PDF is [here](https://github.com/georgebarwood/pdf/blob/master/Example3.pdf).  Do you have any ideas on why, or suggestions on how I can find out what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It could be as simple as a bug in your iPhone PDF viewing app.

If it tends to view correctly on different 3rd party viewers (including and excluding genuine Adobe technology) I'd lean towards that and inquire with the company making the app for them to formally investigate.